# Getting an error that doesn't seem to make much sense.

Tags: python, debugging, dictionary, pdb

I keep getting an error that's referencing one of my Dictionaries in the code. But I can't seem to find anything that would be causing the problem. Something is probably slipping past my eyes, but here's the error from *command line pdb* anyways.

To explain what's going on, this is a rather large dictionary and it's telling me this is giving the program a 'Syntax Error: Invalid Syntax'. The arrow doesn't make much sense in telling me what....  Keynote again this is the result from pdb.

```
distinctiveFeatures = ({1:'Beak',2:'Blood-Drenched',3:'Boiling or Steaming B
ody',4:'Constantly Shedding',5:'Distinctive Markings',6:'Elongated Neck',7:'Hood
',8:'Expanded bone Structure',9:'Albino',10:'Eye Stalks',11:'Glowing Eyes',12:'H
air',13:'Horns',14:'Lizard-Like Fin',15:'Fish-Like Fin',16:'Icy or Cold Body',17
:'Illusionary Features',18:'Metal-Like Features',19:'Multiple Arms',20:'Multiple
Heads',21:'Antlers',22:'Multiple Legs',23:'Multiple Eyes',24:'Stinger',25:'Odor
',26:'On Fire',27:'Oozing Sores',28:'Plant Features',29:'Prehensile Tongue',30:'
Pulsating Skin',31:'Faces',32:'Rocklike Features',33:'Rubber boned',34:'Rubbery
Body',35:'Scales',36:'Serpent Appendages',37:'Shade Form',38:'Shambling Gait',39
:'Shell',40:'Shimmering Body',41:'Skeletal Appearance',42:'Slimy',43:'Speech',44
:'Suction Cups on Limbs',45:'Tail',46:'Tentacles',47:'Transparent',48:'Unusual C
olor',49:'Weapons for Hands',50:'Wet or Drenched Body'51:'Wings',52:'Mechanical
Features',53:'Multiple Features',54:'Special'})



                                                       ^
```

Comment: This shouldn't really be a dictionary - since the keys are all integers and there aren't any missing ones, you could just use a list.

Comment: @silentjudas like `distinctiveFeatures = ['Beak', 'Blood-Drenched'...'` p.s. use backticks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]You are missing a comma.

By the way, why do you put the [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) between brackets?
You can do `({ ..},)` to make the dictionary the first element of a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences),
or just `{..}` for a plain dictionary

Using an editor that shows syntax coloring (like e.g. [Idle](http://ai.uga.edu/mc/idle%5Cindex.html) or [SciTe](http://wiki.python.org/moin/SciTe)) helps a lot.

Because your keys are all integers, perhaps an easier option would be to make a [list](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list):

```
distinctiveFeatures = ['Beak', 'Blood-Drenched', 'Boiling or Steaming Body', 'Constantly Shedding', 'Distinctive Markings', 'Elongated Neck', 'Hood', 'Expanded bone Structure', 'Albino', 'Eye Stalks', 'Glowing Eyes', 'Hair', 'Horns', 'Lizard-Like Fin', 'Fish-Like Fin', 'Icy or Cold Body', 'Illusionary Features', 'Metal-Like Features', 'Multiple Arms', 'MultipleHeads', 'Antlers', 'Multiple Legs', 'Multiple Eyes', 'Stinger', 'Odor', 'On Fire', 'Oozing Sores', 'Plant Features', 'Prehensile Tongue', 'Pulsating Skin', 'Faces', 'Rocklike Features', 'Rubber boned', 'RubberyBody', 'Scales', 'Serpent Appendages', 'Shade Form', 'Shambling Gait', 'Shell', 'Shimmering Body', 'Skeletal Appearance', 'Slimy', 'Speech', 'Suction Cups on Limbs', 'Tail', 'Tentacles', 'Transparent', 'Unusual Color', 'Weapons for Hands', 'Wet or Drenched Body', 'Wings', 'MechanicalFeatures', 'Multiple Features', 'Special']
```

to get your element:

```
distinctiveFeatures[0]
```

gives

```
'Beak'
```

Comment: It's the way I first saw it written out; didn't realize it didn't need them. Also, I use Notepad++ which does a pretty good job, but a long list of words and commas isn't easy to notice minor faults even with coloration...

Never heard of any of those three you mentioned. I'll have to look into them.

Comment: *reads back up* wait, you can do that? well that's far nicer looking than what I've been typing up!   Also, I can't upvote yet due to being new (low rep and all that). However, I can set you as chosen

Comment: I'm honored by your choice! What do you mean with 'reads back up'?

Comment: I meant I was reading back over your edits for your main answer, where you explained the "easier option" of making them a list.

Comment: hahaha, I see... I was looking where the heck I wrote 'reads back up', my mistake... Note I added another lightweight text editor option (SciTe) which is actually my favorite because it has some autocompletion functionality. If you get real serious, look into [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with [Pydev](http://pydev.org/)

Answer (score 7):

Missing comma just before 51.

In future, to help trace this kind of error, its helpful not to put everything on one giant line, split it across several lines. That way the arrow will be more helpful.

Comment: @silentjudas, Push enter. You can put whitespace anywhere you like inside the dictionary definition. I'd put a newline after every comma.

Comment: oh, ha. Okay, I was worried that might screw up the syntax

Answer (score 2):

Element 50 is missing a trailing comma.

You can simplify this line to debug such errors. Start by removing half of the string between the curly braces.

If the problem persists, continue halving the remainder until you find the tiny piece that caused the error, and correct it.